# Jquery Ajax get regular updates from Server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to do some update in my Server and all i need is regular updates from server. How do i achieve that?  Not sure if it is quite possible without splitting into individual calls.

My JS is something like this :

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/Generic/generate",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
```

in my controller

```
      public string Generate() {
       list < myClass > allItems = Getcount(myitems);
       log("x number of Items Received from Database");

       foreach(var ab in allItems) {
            if (ab.Type == "Include") {
             log(ab.Name + "is included")'
            } 
            else {
             log(ab.Name + " is excluded");
            }

         }
        log("All Transactions Success");
        return "Success");
     }
```

in the above , i am looking for a way to get all the log statements while the function is being performed. This way i can provide regular updates to the user.

Note: the actual method is lot bigger and involves lot of steps and sub steps.  Since it takes around 10 minutes to execute the whole process - Users have no clue what is happening. Provided regular updates would help.

Comment: You should look into SignalR. It allows you to push messages from the server to the client. https://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 0):

You either need one way data flow like Server Sent Events or two way like WebSockets, SignalR, etc. [Here's an article describing both](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)